# Generated sources with API-First development in jhipster

Tags: java, jhipster, openapi-generator

I'm trying to generate a new service in jhipster with openapi generator, but generated sources are created on builddirectory (target) so not useful to override those and add my logic. What should I change in my process?

I created the swagger code, and run generate sources as suggested on jhipster documentation: https://www.jhipster.tech/doing-api-first-development/

```java
openapi: '3.0.1'
info:
  title: 'Example'
  version: 0.0.1
servers:
  - url: http://localhost:8080
    description: Development server
  - url: https://localhost:8080
    description: Development server with TLS Profile
paths:
  /assessments/{reference}:
    get:
      summary: active assessments for a given reference
      operationId: getAssessmentsByDevice
      description: |
        By passing a unique identifier reference, you can get active assessments for that device
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: reference
          description: unique device identifier
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: active assessments for a device
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  type: string
        '400':
          description: bad input parameter
        '404':
          description: reference not found
```

and running generator:

```
[INFO] OpenAPI Generator: spring (server)
[INFO] Generator 'spring' is considered stable.
[INFO] ----------------------------------
[INFO] Environment variable JAVA_POST_PROCESS_FILE not defined so the Java code may not be properly formatted. To define it, try 'export JAVA_POST_PROCESS_FILE="/usr/local/bin/clang-format -i"' (Linux/Mac)
[INFO] NOTE: To enable file post-processing, 'enablePostProcessFile' must be set to `true` (--enable-post-process-file for CLI).
[INFO] Invoker Package Name, originally not set, is now derived from api package name: com.hcb.happyratingmodel.web
[INFO] Processing operation getAssessmentsByDevice
[INFO] writing file C:\Users\cduquemarcos\Documents\Documentation\Projects\Personal\example\target\generated-sources\openapi\src\main\java\com\hcb\example\web\api\AssessmentsApiController.java
[INFO] writing file C:\Users\cduquemarcos\Documents\Documentation\Projects\Personal\example\target\generated-sources\openapi\src\main\java\com\hcb\example\web\api\AssessmentsApi.java
[INFO] writing file C:\Users\cduquemarcos\Documents\Documentation\Projects\Personal\example\target\generated-sources\openapi\src\main\java\com\hcb\example\web\api\AssessmentsApiDelegate.java
[INFO] writing file C:\Users\cduquemarcos\Documents\Documentation\Projects\Personal\example\target\generated-sources\openapi\src/main/java\com\hcb\example\web\api\ApiUtil.java
[INFO] writing file C:\Users\cduquemarcos\Documents\Documentation\Projects\Personal\example\target\generated-sources\openapi\.openapi-generator\VERSION
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I was expecting those classes will be generated under SRC folder to be available to be extended by my implementation.
Is my understanding correct? Should I just copy manually those to my source folder?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes if you want to edit those, you can copy them manually. The plug-in is set up this way so the source of truth is the openapi code and you extend the generated interface.

Answer (score 0):

The default output path is *${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/openapi*. You can modify this by changing it with the *output* property in the configuration settings or by setting it globally through the *openapi.generator.maven.plugin.output* property.

More details and other config options here: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin